# Galería de imagenes modificando el IMG de HTML

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

Estoy haciendo una galería de imágenes sencilla, para lo cual uso una página JSP, CSS y JavaScript. Las imágenes las obtengo de un directorio en el servidor web. No tengo mayor problema cuando son pocas imágenes, pero cuando son cientos de ellas, se muere el browser internet explorer, debido a que se satura la memoria.

Este es mi código:

```js
<script>
        //la imagen se compone de un nombre + un secuencial
            var nombreBaseImagen = "<%=listaArchivos[3]%>";  //este es el nombre del archivo jpg
        var cantidadImagenes = <%=listaArchivos[4]%>;    //esta es la cantidad de imagenes
        var rutaImagen="temp/";  //la ruta donde se encuentran las imagenes
        muestra=0; //el numero secuencial de mi imagen
        
        function inicio() {
         pantalla=document.getElementById("visor"); //elemento pantalla para ver las fotos.
         titulo=document.getElementById("mititulo"); //el titulo de la imagen
              //seteo el src de mi tag imagen:
         document.getElementById('typeImg').src = "../"+rutaImagen+nombreBaseImagen+muestra+".jpg"; 
         titulo.innerHTML = "Imagen 1 de "+cantidadImagenes;
        }
        
            //esta funcion es para la galería
        function mueve(opcion) { //cambio de imagen     
               switch (opcion) { //opciones para los distintos botones
                case "avance": //botón de avanza 1
                 muestra++;
                 if (muestra>=cantidadImagenes) { muestra=0; } //si llegamos al final empieza de nuevo.
                 estilo="derecho"; //la transición será de derecha a izquierda
                 break;
                case "fin": //botón avanza hasta el final.
                 muestra=cantidadImagenes-1;
                 estilo="derecho";
                 break;
                case "retro": //botón retrodede 1
                 muestra--;
                 if (muestra<0) { muestra=cantidadImagenes-1; } //si retrocedemos desde el principio va al final
                 estilo="izquierdo" //la transición será de izquierda a derecha
                 break;
               case "prin": //retroceder al principio
                 muestra=0
                 estilo="izquierdo"
                 break
               }
               
               document.getElementById('typeImg').src = "../"+rutaImagen+nombreBaseImagen+muestra+".jpg";
         titulo.innerHTML = "Imagen "+(muestra+1)+" de "+cantidadImagenes;
        }  
        
       </script>
```

```
<body onload="inicio()" leftmargin="30px" rightmargin="30px" topmargin="0" bottommargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" class="fondo">
                <div id="visor">
                   <!-- colocaremos aquí la foto nueva mediante javascript -->
                     <!-- Esta es la foto saliente al pulsar algún botón -->
                   <div id="fotoSale">
                     <img id="typeImg" src="../temp/imagen"/>
                   </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Elemento del pie de foto, aparte del texto colocamos aquí los botones que 
                     permitirán cambiar de imagen. -->
                <div id="piefoto">
                   <!-- Botones para retroceso de imagen -->
                   <div id="controlesre">
                      <img src="../imgs/rew.gif" alt="principio" width="30" onclick="mueve('prin')" />
                      <img src="../imgs/atras.gif" alt="atras" width="30" onclick="mueve('retro')" />
                   </div>
                   <!-- Botones para avance de imagen -->
                   <div id="controlesav">
                      <img src="../imgs/play.gif" alt="avance" width="30" onclick="mueve('avance')" />
                      <img src="../imgs/avv.gif" alt="final" width="30" onclick="mueve('fin')" />
                   </div>
                   <!-- Texto del pie de foto -->
                   <div id="mititulo">ok</div> 
                </div>
    </body>
```

```html
<style type="text/css">
     /*titulo de la página*/
     h1 { font: bold 1.5em garamond; text-align: center; }
     /*visor o pantalla*/
     #visor { position: absolute; left: 250px; top: 20px; width: 500px; height: 650px; background-color: white; overflow: hidden;  }
     #visor img { max-width: 500px; max-height: 620px;}
     /*foto saliente y foto entrante*/
     #fotoSale { position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; }
     #fotoEntra { position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; }
     /*Elementos al pie de foto*/
     #piefoto { position: absolute; left: 250px; top: 650px; width: 500px; height: 30px;
         background-color: silver; }
     /*controles de cambio de imagen*/
     #controlesre { position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; }
     #controlesav { position: absolute; top: 0px; right: 0px; }
     #controlesre img, #controlesav img { cursor: pointer }
     /*texto de pie de foto*/
     #mititulo { position: absolute; top: 5px; left: 70px; font: normal 12px arial; }
    </style>
```

El programa funciona correctamente, cuando la galería obtiene unas 10 imagenes del directorio no hay problema, pero si se cargan 100 imágenes se muere el browser, debido a que se satura la memoria. Alguna sugerencia?[image: Este es el monitor de recursos que se incrementa cada vez que se carga la siguiente imagen][image: Esta es mi pagina jsp en ejecucion]

Comment: No cargues imágenes muy pesadas al browser, en su lugar usa miniaturas.

Comment: No uses IE11, es una cosa muy inútil hoy en dia en este universo con Firefox o Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Parece que tu problema se debe a un bug conocido de internet explorer. Una fuga de memoria, más concretamente ([enlace](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/6ba039ec-8438-4225-ba7c-bad7e195a105/img-tags-src-updation-causing-memory-leaks?forum=iewebdevelopment)). En la MSDN hay un [tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/jj819178.aspx) para depurar memory leaks como la tuya. Pero creo que bastaría con que, antes que nada, pruebas a reemplazar la imagen, en lugar de modificar el atributo `src`.

```
    var node = document.getElementById('typeImg');
    var parent = node.parentNode;
    parent.removeChild(node);
    var imgNode = document.createElement('img');
    imgNode.setAttribute("src","../"+rutaImagen+nombreBaseImagen+muestra+".jpg");
    node.appendChild(imgNode);
```

Esto lo he hecho de memoria pero si hay algun fallo será de sintaxis, prueba y nos dices. En cualquier caso, te recomiendo que pruebes a usar jQuery porque, por ejemplo, lo que escrito yo, es un par de líneas con esta librería. (Y alguno saldrá que dice que lo hace en una sola, seguro).

En cualquier caso, sí te recomiendo encarecidamente que elimines las llamadas a javascript del HTML (onload(), onclick()...) porque no es buena práctica, es mejor definir los even listeners desde el script y así tu código es más robusto y ante todo, reutilizable.